# How do I transform mined ETH to cash?

Tags: ether

I'm new to the blockchain but I'm reading every day consistently and since I am a coder I'm sure it will be a really interesting venture for me :)

Nevertheless, the whole thing started with the ideea of mining ETH. It's going to be a hobby mining (at least at the beginning).

I know how to set up my rig to mine with a pool, but I need a really safe wallet (not web-based), I found Mist should be good, but any other recommendations are welcome, and also I need to know that there exists a way for me to cash out my earned ETH from mining, in USD let's say, and then into my bank account or VISA.

How is this accomplished ? (the sending ETH from very secure wallet to a place where you can actually cash out the ETH).

thanks!